# Android login and registration with PHP MySQL and SQLite FAIL

Tags: java, android

I've been following the Androidhive tutorial for login and registration with php mysql and sqlite- https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ but there seems to be some issue with connecting to the server. 
The logcat shows the error Unexpected response code 403 for http://192.168.x.x/android_login_api/register.php/ and also registration error:null

[logcat screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77YRo.jpg)

It shows 404 not found when I search the url - http://192.168.x.x/android_login_api/login.php on my browser. I'm sure this is my correct ip address.The android device connected and the laptop are both on the same wifi. And I've tried several things to solve the network issues by reading similar questions and answers but still no luck.

I've done everything in the tutorial but when I try to register it doesn't work and an empty toast shows and then disappears.
I've checked and rechecked the code but can't seem to get to a solution. Please help.

Comment: please post ALL your code and errors here in your question

Comment: Please show your http server config!

Answer (score 0):

Go to - C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

Check if

'require local' is there if yes then change to

'Require all granted'

The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code which means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason.
Also make sure you're accessing the correct url..

Comment: I changed 'require local' to 'require all granted' but still the 404 not found error is showing. The logcat also shows the same errors. I'm quite sure I'm accessing the correct url.